# how to call an image button event in a function

Tags: asp.net

i need  to call an image button event in a  function.  how to call

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

this  my function

```
 void  bindData()
{
// here i nee  to cal the  above image button event
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to call your event with empty parameters :

```
void  bindData()
{
    ImageButton1_Click(null, new ImageClickEventArgs(0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
void bindData()
{
    // here i nee  to cal the  above image button event
    ImageButton1_Click(null, null);
}
```

You can also send in a control as the sender argument if you want to use it and you could also send in some arguements by sending in a n ImageClickEventArgs object but neither are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `ImageButton1_Click(image, new ImageClickEventArgs(0, 0)` where the image is the image you want to simulate the click event on. Or you can send in null parameters. But the best way is to create another method with the logic inside `ImageButton1_Click` and place a call to it inside the click event, and anywhere else that is necessary.